# PHP comparing int to string

Tags: php

Code is as follows

```
function subscribe($api, $target_list_name, $fname, $lname, $email_to_subscribe, $membership_level_id) {
    $temp_membership_name = "";
    if ((int) $membership_level_id == 2) {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 1";
    } elseif ((int) $membership_level_id == 5) {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 2";
    } else {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 3";
    }
}
```

For some reason Option 3 is always the outcome regardless, I've tested with $membership_level_id set to 2 and 5, both times the else block executes.

Cant figure out why any tips?

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($membership_level_id);`.

Comment: As long as the value of $membership_level_id is either 2 or 5 (as string or number) it will enter one of the cases. You are using double equal signs, so you don't even need the (int), it wont check for type. 5 == "5", "2" == 2, "2" !== 2.

Comment: I don't think one of the answers below is a solution, the problem probably occurs prior to your function call. Where does $membership_level_id come from?

Answer (score 1):

```
function subscribe($api, $target_list_name, $fname, $lname, $email_to_subscribe, $membership_level_id) {
    $temp_membership_name = "shevehferhgifsfshfishfishf";
    if ((int) $membership_level_id == 2) {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 1";
    } elseif ((int) $membershipMWAHHAHAHHAHAHA_level_id == 5) {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 2";
    } else {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 3";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a **space** in `else if` in your code.
I have tested it and you can have a look:

**Test Here:** https://eval.in/83367

```
function subscribe($api, $target_list_name, $fname, $lname, $email_to_subscribe, $membership_level_id) {
    $temp_membership_name = "";

    if ((int) $membership_level_id == 2) {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 1";
    } else if ((int) $membership_level_id == 5) {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 2";
    } else {
        $temp_membership_name = "Option 3";
    }

    return $temp_membership_name;
}

echo subscribe("", "", "", "", "", "2") . "   ";
echo subscribe("", "", "", "", "", 2);
```

Output:

```
Option 1   Option 1
```

Comment: you have missed a space in else if in your code. Can you test and confirm ? @Nizzle

Comment: @Nizzle did you try it?

Comment: Tried it, it still always sets $temp_membership_name to "Option 3"

Comment: @Nizzle :  did you see my link? it shows correct output. See here: https://eval.in/83372    It is working.you should replace your subscribe function with my function. There is no problem in this function if it is not working in your code then problem in somewhere else.

Comment: @Nizzle :Your posted problems are solved in my given link. So if you have problem in somewhere else you should open as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your input. php does automatic type conversion so even if the number is stored as a string it should still evaluate. The type conversion isn't necessary. Either

a) your code is not supplying the argument correctly (check spelling?)

b) there is a space or non-numeric value in the first character of your input causing the type conversion to return a value of 0 or

c) some other part of your function is messing with the variable

I ran the code you posted directly and it works fine with integers or text. I take it you're setting $membership_level_id indirectly, you should check your inputs to make sure the function is actually receiving what you think it is.

Answer (score -1):

What about using a "switch" statement and then provide a "default" option which will be the standard one?

that said... `if ((int)$membership_level_id == 2)`

PHP transform text to numbers alone.

so... what about check if `$membership_level_id` is numeric before using the value?

like

```
`if(is_numeric($_membership_level_id))
{
//number.
} else {
// not a number.
}`
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this as a solution.

```
 if ($membership_level_id == "2") {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 1";
 } elseif ($membership_level_id == "5") {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 2";
 } else {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 3";
 }
```

Comment: Uhm, how is this a 'solution'?

Comment: because $membership_level_id is a string so the value to compare must be a string also.

Comment: @user3045072 That's wrong. PHP automatically converts the string to an integer when comparing strings and integers. This technique is called "type juggling": http://php.net/ternary

Answer (score -4):

```
function subscribe($api,$target_list_name,$fname,$lname,$email_to_subscribe, $membership_level_id)
{

     $temp_membership_name = "";

 if ($membership_level_id == "2") {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 1";
 } elseif ($membership_level_id =="5") {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 2";
 } else {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 3";
 }
}
```

try to use this code or troubleshoot the values of $member_level_id

```
function subscribe($api,$target_list_name,$fname,$lname,$email_to_subscribe, $membership_level_id)
{

     $temp_membership_name = "";
     echo $membership_level_id;exit;
 if ((int)$membership_level_id == '2') {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 1";
 } elseif ((int)$membership_level_id =='5') {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 2";
 } else {
     $temp_membership_name = "Option 3";
 }
}
```